# UVA problems submission requirements

Tags: c

I'm so confused as what UVA's requirements for a correct answer is as I've been doing some simple problems but all my code that I submitted has all came out as wrong even though I have tested it out and the outputs are all correct. I've even compared my code to other people's and the code is "almost" the same. For example is this problem no.12250

This is my code which is wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int i=1;
    char sen[80];
    
    while(scanf("%s",&sen)!=EOF){
            if(!strcmp(sen,"HELLO")) {
                printf("Case %d: ENGLISH\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"HOLA")) { 
                printf("Case %d: SPANISH\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"HALLO")) { 
                printf("Case %d: GERMAN\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"BONJOUR")) { 
                printf("Case %d: FRENCH\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"CIAO")) { 
                printf("Case %d: ITALIAN\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"ZDRAVSTVUJTE")) { 
                printf("Case %d: RUSSIAN\n",i);
            }
            else if(!strcmp(sen,"#")) { 
                break;
            }
            else{ 
                printf("case %d: UNKNOWN\n",i);
            }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

and this is a code which is accepted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char word[80];
    int i = 1;

    while (scanf("%s", &word) != EOF) {
        if (strcmp(word, "#") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "HOLA") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: SPANISH\n", i);
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "HELLO") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: ENGLISH\n", i);
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "HALLO") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: GERMAN\n", i);
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "BONJOUR") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: FRENCH\n", i);
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "CIAO") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: ITALIAN\n", i);
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, "ZDRAVSTVUJTE") == 0) {
            printf("Case %d: RUSSIAN\n", i);
        }
        else {
            printf("Case %d: UNKNOWN\n", i);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can't find where my mistake is and I will really appreciate some help. Thank You

Comment: `case %d: UNKNOWN` is wrong because lowercase `c` is used.

Comment: Also note that `scanf("%s",&sen)` and `scanf("%s",&word)` invokes *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type: `char*` is expected but `char(*)[80]` is passed. You should remove the `&`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you very much! Changing that lowercase `c` apparently is enough. Such a silly mistake haha